# Page Not Found error showing after Firebase Deploy

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I created a testing project by Angular 6 and Tried to deploy it on Google Firebase. I followed these instructions sequence to proceed.

1. Google Login
2. Create Firebase new project
3. Go to Firebase console -> Hosting -> Get Start
4. Install firebase tools by NPM
5. Move to the Project Directory
6. Check the output by `ng serve`
7. Build the project by `ng build --prod`
8. Login to the project by `sudo firebase login`
9. Initialize project by 1sudo firebase init1 with default values (default folder set to Dist and single-page-app: Yes)
10. delete the Dist folder and re build
11. deploy project by `sudo firebase deploy`

After doing the sequence, when I move to the particular domain provided by firebase, It showing the 404 Page Not Found Error. I'm pretty sure that the instruction sequence is correct. What is the wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change angular.json output path to dist. Your sequence is correct and that output path must be different from dist.